# How to use Rest Cient components in TypeLibrary Delphi projects?

Tags: delphi

I created a simple Win form application in Delphi and using the below code by dropping RestClient components in the form. Everything works fine.
Now, I want to use the same functionality in TypeLib, coz i want a DLL output and consume this DLL in .Net.

Can you please let me know how to use the Rest components

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, REST.Types, REST.Client,
  Data.Bind.Components, Data.Bind.ObjectScope;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
    RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
    RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LHTTP: TRESTClient;
  LRequest: TRESTRequest;
  LResponse: TRESTResponse;

begin
  LHTTP := TRESTClient.Create('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');

  try
    LRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(LHTTP);
    LRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
    LRequest.Execute;

    Memo1.Lines.Text := LRequest.Response.Content;
  finally
    LHTTP.Free;
  end;


end;
end.
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the native .NET features to access the web service?

Comment: It's not only restricted to Web services, but I am also adding other functionalities. moreover, Delphi is not as easy to decompile like .Net using a .Net reflector